# iphone multitask

Tags: iphone, multitasking

I want to make my iphone run application in the background.I know there is a program called "backgrounder",but it isn't I want.What should I do?

Comment: Explain how "backgrounder" isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is flat out not allowed... period.

You may want to look into the development community for jailbroken phones. I think there are projects like that there, although you are severely cutting off your userbase.